# Counting only data points which are within a specified radius of other data points?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location, code-review

I wanted to know if I am on the right track here with what I am trying to do. I have two shapefiles, the first contains point data for all the businesses in DC and the other contains point data all the Metro stations in DC. What I am trying to accomplish is to find all the businesses that are within a 500 Meter radius of a metro station, then find all coffee shops that are within a 500 meter radius of a metro station.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy    
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Users/new/Desktop/'   
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer('DC_POI.shp','DCPts')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer('DC_MetroStations.shp','StationPts')   
arcpy.Buffer_analysis('StationPts','MyShapefile.shp','500 Meters','#','#','#','#','#') 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('DCPts','intersect','StationPts')
arcpy.SelectByAttribute_management('DCPts','SUBSET_SELECTION',"category='CoffeeShop'")  
counter = arcpy.GetCount_management('DCPTs')
print(counter)
```

when it prints counter, it is 0. I want to after every selection analysis to count the number of POI that are still selected in
the layer.

I know I should use buffer analysis to buffer the metro stations by the that radius and create a new shapefile. So I think that was accomplished.
And then use Select Layer By Location analysis that way I select all POI that intersect the new buffered dataset.

Comment: Why are you asking if it will work? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: @Jon I don't know if it logically makes sense. I ran the program and it created the MyShapefile.shp on my desktop but when I went to open it nothing appears on Arcmap. Also nothing prints for the print(counter)

Comment: That is vital information to include in your question if you wish to get a useful answer! (I don't use Arc or arcpy, so I won't be much help).

Comment: @Jon I updated. Also when it prints it comes up 0

Comment: Code now creates a map of pts. Trying now to determine if it is correct. The print is still 0.

Comment: Update your question with changes you've made to the code, as well as the new outputs you're getting...

Comment: @Jon it's updated.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code in that way: 
(Brief description is in the code)

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Users/new/Desktop/'    
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer('DC_POI.shp','DCPts')    
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer('DC_MetroStations.shp','StationPts')

# Create buffers   
arcpy.Buffer_analysis('StationPts','MyShapefile.shp','500 Meters')

# Load buffer to memory
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer('MyShapefile.shp','Buffer')

# Select points which intersects with buffers
# You must select points in buffer 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('DCPts', 'INTERSECT', 'Buffer')

counter1 = arcpy.GetCount_management('DCPTs')
print("Businesses within 500m radius of a metro station: " + str(counter1) )

# Select coffee shops from just selected points
arcpy.SelectByAttribute_management('DCPts', 
                                   'SUBSET_SELECTION',
                                   "category='CoffeeShop'")

counter2 = arcpy.GetCount_management('DCPTs')    
print("CoffeeShops within 500m radius of a metro station: " + str(counter2) )
```

Comment: By passing a search distance to *SelectLayerByLocation*, you can bypass the buffering. `SelectLayerByLocation_management('DCPts', 'INTERSECT', 'StationPts', '500 METERS')`